# Could not load file or assembly System.ServiceModel

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I recently started converting an ASP.NET web application to ASP.NET Core. 
I was earlier making use of System.ServiceModel for [WS2007HttpBinding](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.ws2007httpbinding(v=vs.110).aspx) and `System.IdentityModel`, however in ASP.NET Core I get the following error:

> Could not load file or assembly `System.ServiceModel`

Is `System.ServiceModel` deprecated for ASP.NET Core or is there an alternative workaround for it?

Comment: WCF does not exist on .NET Core, so there's no `System.ServiceModel`

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto thanks for d info

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can download it from NuGet the specific package if you are just trying to reference the `WS2007HttpBinding`